# perl: call hash values as methods

Tags: perl, hash

I have an usual  hash or hashref.

```
my %hash; $hash{'key'} = 'value';
```

not very easy all this quote marks and curly brackets
I know there is a trick to call hash values like methods:

```
$hash->key = 'value'; # even no need for round brackets !
```

May be to use some magick module, I know it exist, I have seen this code once:

```
use CallHashLikeMethods 'hash';
$hash->key = 'value';
```

Of course, I can write the class for this hash and then TIE it, but it is very manual;
I looking for a magic moduule which prepares hash automatically. I just forget it's name

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking to do is a fairly bad idea:

- Maintainability: When a hash access doesn't look like a hash access, that's bad.
- Performance: Method calls are much more expensive than hash accesses.
- Correctness: An overdose of cleverness could make other clever code break. Keep your code simple and stupid.

Furthermore, this will *not* save you any typing, because the keys in a hash access are auto-quoted:

```
$hash{key} = 'value';
$hash->key = 'value';
```

… as long as the key is a valid bareword.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any pre-written CPAN modules that do this, but it's not exactly difficult...

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub HASH::AUTOLOAD :lvalue {
  my ($key) = ($HASH::AUTOLOAD =~ /(\w+)\z/);
  shift->{$key};
}

my $hash = {
  foo => 1,
  bar => 0,  # not 2
  baz => 3,
};

bless($hash, 'HASH');

$hash->bar = 1;
$hash->bar++;

say $hash->foo;
say $hash->bar;
say $hash->baz;
```

I agree with amon though - normal hash access will be clearer and faster, and the syntax is not exactly onerous.

**Update:** found a CPAN module for it: [Hash::AsObject](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash%3a%3aAsObject).

Comment: Re "and the syntax is not exactly onerous", Yeah, especially if you stop using needless quotes and use `$hash{key}` instead of `$hash{'key'}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a fixed set of keys as structure values, you might like `Struct::Dumb`

```
use Struct::Dumb;

struct Point => ['x', 'y', 'z'];

my $p = Point(10, 20, 30);
$p->x = 40;
```